# How to get a query that only displays items that are in the present or future in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I have this query:

```
$events = db_query("SELECT e.name, e.event_date, e.time, e.data, e.picture, e.event_type, v.latitude, v.longitude, v.address, v.name as vname 
FROM events e INNER JOIN venues v ON e.vid=v.vid 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$q."', event_type)>0 
AND e.event_date > (SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
GROUP BY e.name");
```

And it all works fine except the date selection. I would like this query to list only items that are of the day before or in the future but at the moment it lists all items. Any pointers as to where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: If I remove the first "WHERE" clause then the query executes correctly and only returns the items with a date in the future.

The whole query looks like this:

```
SELECT e.name, e.event_date, e.time, e.data, e.picture, e.event_type, v.latitude, v.longitude, v.address, v.name as vname 
FROM events e INNER JOIN venues v ON e.vid=v.vid 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('liveSports', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('dancing', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('drinksDeals', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('pubQuiz', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('boardGames', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('fussball', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('speedDating', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('pool', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('liveMusic', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('foodDeals', e.event_type)>0
AND e.event_date >= (SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY e.name
```

I have a feeling that the issue might be with the amount of ORing going on here. If I reduce the size of the query in that way, the results are returned as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: What format is event_date in?

Comment: event_date is YYYY-MM-DD. I added a small edit.

Comment: Can you post what the query looks like *after* it is generated?  In other words with the $q value plugged in?  I get the feeling that something isn't escaped correctly.

Comment: maybe just a typo, but make sure event_type in the FIND_IN_SET is associated with it's table. ex: e.event_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, but I bet you wanted to OR all the FIND_IN_SETs together, THEN check the date on all of them. I added parens. Also, you didn't need the subquery (SELECT...) arround the DATE_SUB.

```
SELECT e.name, e.event_date, e.time, e.data, e.picture, e.event_type, v.latitude, v.longitude, v.address, v.name as vname 
FROM events e INNER JOIN venues v ON e.vid=v.vid 
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET('liveSports', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('dancing', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('drinksDeals', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('pubQuiz', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('boardGames', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('fussball', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('speedDating', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('pool', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('liveMusic', event_type)>0 
OR FIND_IN_SET('foodDeals', e.event_type)>0)
AND e.event_date >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY e.name
```

Comment: Woops, looks like I found out about the same time you did. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
e.event_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(subdate(current_date, 1))
```

or, for example:

```
e.event_date > subdate(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

BTW, it would be fine, to strip your SELECT of all conditons except Date, maximally simplify it and then make it to work. After that return back other SELECT elements.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. NOW() returns a date formatted like this: YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS. In this case I only need the YYYY-MM-DD, that's why I'm using CURDATE(). Similarly for UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Please, put that info into the question.

Comment: AFAIK, you can easily compare YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS and YYYY-MM-DD dates. The starting part is the same.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - I edited my question to add a little more information. I have a feeling the issue is not with the date filter itself but with the FIND_IN_SET that comes before it. Thanks again for your response though.

Comment: +1. I am glad you have found the answer. It is a pleasure to meet a polite person here. Mostly, politeness is prohibited and persecuted on these pages. :-(